# difference # and {} or nohing in item on SASS

Tags: sass

```
$list: (orange, purple, teal);

//Add your each-loop here
@each $item in $list {
  .{$item} {
    background: $item;
  }
}
```

$list: (orange, purple, teal);

```
//Add your each-loop here
@each $item in $list {
  .$item {
    background: $item;
  }
}
```

$list: (orange, purple, teal);

```
//Add your each-loop here
@each $item in $list {
  .#{$item} {
    background: $item;
  }
}
```

I am new to SASS,when I practising this all gave me same result.What is difference between them?# {} or nothing why we just use nothing

Answer (score 0):

Only `$item` when you don't want to add anything more. SASS use `#{}` to separate  its code from CSS. So if you want to select a class you need `.#{$item}`.